# How to assign value to variable outside the function in $on AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am calling factory before we call $on , is there way to assign `$scope.attestorObj.riskAssessmentRoleAsgnKey` to `roleAsgnKy` value that is global variable.New to angularJS any help will be appreciated.

So far tried code...

main.js

```
var roleAsgnKy;
              $scope.filesGridOptions = attestorConfig.getAttestorHistoryFile();
              $scope.filesGridOptions.dataSourceattestorFactory.getFilesHistoryDataSource(roleAsgnKy);

    $scope.$on('addEditAttest',function(s,attestorObj){
               $scope.attestorObj = attestorObj;
               $scope.attestorObj.riskAssessmentRoleAsgnKey = roleAsgnKy;
             });
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do... you want to make $scope.attestorObj.riskAssessmentRoleAsgnKey a global variable instead of limited to its current scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment about it wanting to be a global variable you have two options

1) Setup a service/factory to store and access that variable. That way you can set and get it from anywhere in your app https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

2) Make it a variable within $rootScope, which you can inject into any controller and access or change from anywhere as well https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope

It's generally considered best practice to use a service for your style of issue, and you can wrap any logic needed around the variable there as well.